# Visualizing three index cylindrical modes logic

Tags: resonator

From rectangular waveguide I know that *nml* means we have half wave behavior in each direction.

How do I imagine the shape of a *nml* mode in cylindrical resonator by its indexes?

Are there any visual intuitions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cylindrical resonator, an nml mode represents a standing wave pattern with n radial nodes, m azimuthal nodes and l angular nodes. The shape of this mode is formed by the constructive and destructive interference of the electric and magnetic fields within the resonator.

One way to imagine the shape of an nml mode in a cylindrical resonator is to think of it as a three-dimensional pattern of nodes and antinodes. The radial nodes correspond to points in the resonator where the electric and magnetic fields cancel each other out, while the azimuthal and angular nodes represent regions of constructive interference where the fields add up.

For example, an nml=101 mode in a cylindrical resonator would have one radial node, zero azimuthal nodes, and one angular node. This would result in a mode with a doughnut-shaped electric field, with a region of zero field intensity along the axis of the cylinder.

Visualizing these modes can be challenging, but there are software programs that can generate three-dimensional representations of these fields, such as COMSOL Multiphysics or MATLAB.",

Comment: Hello ,Could you please add a drawing of the bagle and the nodes that created it?
Thanks.